# Unfolding triangles with different shapes and size?

Tags: css, animation

I'm trying to create an unfolding animation using CSS3.

Basically, I'm trying to unfold 3 triangles on after the other and the triangles have different sizes and shapes but they all make one image.

I'm not sure if this is even possible but I have so far come up with this:

http://jsfiddle.net/wvm15yL4/27/

And this i smy code:

```
@keyframes flip {
   0%       { transform: rotate3d( 0.5, 0.866, 0,  90deg); 
              opacity: 0;}
   0.1%     { transform: rotate3d( 0.5, 0.866, 0,  90deg); 
              opacity: 1;}
  14%       { transform: rotate3d( 0.5, 0.866, 0,   0deg); }
  50%       { transform: rotate3d(-0.5, 0.866, 0,   0deg); }
  63.99%    { transform: rotate3d(-0.5, 0.866, 0, -90deg); 
              opacity: 1;}
  64%, 100% { transform: rotate3d(-0.5, 0.866, 0, -90deg); 
              opacity: 0}
}

.folding-hex {
  height: 69.28px;
  width: 80px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: translateX(40px) rotate(30deg); }

.rotator {
    transform-origin: 20px 37.64px;

}
.rotator:nth-child(1) {
    transform: rotate(0deg); 
}
.rotator:nth-child(2) {
    transform: rotate(60deg); 
}
.rotator:nth-child(3) {
    transform: rotate(120deg); 
}
.rotator:nth-child(4) {
    transform: rotate(180deg); 
}
.rotator:nth-child(5) {
    transform: rotate(240deg); 
}
.rotator:nth-child(6) {
    transform: rotate(300deg); 
}

.triangle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 34.64px 20px 0;
    transform-origin: 20px 37.64px;
    border-color: #E50C4E transparent; 
    animation: flip 3s linear infinite;
}

.rotator:nth-child(2) .triangle {
    border-color: #b5093d transparent; 
    animation-delay: -2.5s;
}
.rotator:nth-child(3) .triangle {
    border-color: #b5093d transparent; 
    animation-delay: -2.0s;
}
.rotator:nth-child(4) .triangle {
    animation-delay: -1.5s;
}

.rotator:nth-child(5) .triangle {
    border-color: #f8799f transparent; 
    animation-delay: -1.0s;
}
.rotator:nth-child(6) .triangle {
    border-color: #f8799f transparent; 
    animation-delay: -0.5s;
}
```

As you can see, it currently animates but its not really unfolding the triangles.

Could someone please advice on this matter?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Basically, trying to unfold the triangles like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/wvm15yL4/28/

Comment: can you be more precise on what you want? ... probably show us the before and after ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif, sure..

Comment: @TemaniAfif,  edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably try to use SVG to define the triangle and have less of code then adjust the transform properties as you want.

Here is a simplified example, hover to unfold:

```css
.unfold {
  margin: 150px;
  position: relative;
  width:100px;
}
.unfold svg {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  stroke:blue;
  stroke-width:2px;
  fill:transparent;
  transform-origin:bottom;
  transform:skewY(-10deg);
  transition:1s all;
}
.unfold svg:last-child {
  transform:skewY(-10deg) rotateX(45deg);
}
.unfold:hover svg:first-child {
  transform-origin:bottom;
  transform:skewY(-10deg) rotateX(-140deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="unfold">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" ><polygon points="2 2,2 98,98 98" /></svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" ><polygon points="98 2,2 98,98 98" /></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: thats nice and very light. but how do i go about unfolding the individual triangles on a loop?

Comment: @williamwolly like the second example you provided, you should apply a different animation to each one and play with delay to have the synchronization

Comment: in my second example, I have multiple divs. in your example there is only 2 SVG. not sure how this would work with just 2 svg elements!

Comment: @williamwolly you apply an animation to each SVG alone :)